# Python: Do I need to sort Dictionary before comparing them?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, data-structures

I wish to compare the output of JSON response with a dictionary that I define. Dictionaries and JSON objects are not ordered.

From my own testing, with this JSON response stored as `res.data`

```
{
    "message": "Staff name and password pair not match",
    "errors": {
        "resource": "Login",
        "field": "staff_authentication",
        "code": "invalid",
        "stack_trace": null
    }
}
```

I do not find [anything that refers to Dictionary comparison operator in Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). I have read articles about sorting dictionary that is loaded from JSON string, but from my own testing the comparison operator works correctly without sorting. 
And comparing with this differently ordered Dictionary, will result in `True`

```
invalid_password_json = dict(
                                    errors=dict(
                                        resource="Login",
                                        code="invalid",
                                        field="staff_authentication",
                                        stack_trace=None,),
                                        message="Staff name and password pair not match",
                                    )
        assert json.loads(res.data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict) == invalid_password_json
```

Do I need to use `json.dumps(my_password, sort_keys=True)` or `json.loads(res.data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict))` to ensure the order before comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to sort the keys of your dictionary, as mentioned in rather old [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/comparisons.html):

> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted
> (key, value) lists compare equal.(5.4) Outcomes other than equality
> are resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined. (5.5)
>
> ... equal. (5.4)
>
> The implementation computes this efficiently, without constructing lists or sorting.
>
> ... defined. (5.5)
>
> Earlier versions of Python used lexicographic comparison of the sorted (key, value) lists, but this was very expensive for the common
> case of comparing for equality. An even earlier version of Python
> compared dictionaries by identity only, but this caused surprises
> because people expected to be able to test a dictionary for emptiness
> by comparing it to {}.

Also, it helps to know that in python, dictionaries are implemented using hash tables and not balanced trees.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual: python compares dictionaries by comparing their sorted key value pairs.
In my opinion this means that even if the keys are not sorted they are compared in a sorted order, which seems the only reasonable way to compare 2 dictionaries. 
So I believe that you **do not need** to `use sort_keys=True` but somehow that could be an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Python dicts are unordered and two dicts compare equal if they have the same key:value pairs (whatever the order), period. So you do not need to sort anything to compare your own dict with one parsed from json.